# Procedural Progressive wave system advice

Tags: game-mechanics, procedural-generation

I am developing a game based on waves. Enemies appear as time passes by and every level the hero must kill all the enemies to move to the next level.

At this time I have 2 types of waves. Progressive waves (enemies are spawned every x secs), All at once waves (enemies are spawned all at once at a moment in time). On the other hand my enemies (5 types) have base features that I want to improve as player moves into more challenging levels

My question is simple: How do you ussually handle this type of wave generation system? For every level I would like to generate a set of wave events (first 5 enemies all at once, then 10 progressively, etc...), after this I must select how many enemies to spawn for every wave and their features (velocity, behaviour, weapon power, etc...).

One solution I have thought about is creating some meanful templates for the wave creation. For example, I colud create 10 spawning process. A process is like:

1. Spawn 5 enemies
2. Wait 10 secs or all enemies died from previous wave
3. Create 10 enemies and spawn all at once. THis would be a spawn process.

Then I could select a random template for each level and scale number of enemies, etc... depending on the level difficulty.

How do you ussually handle this kidn of system?

Cheers.

Comment: For me, it would very much depend on the language being used. OO? Custom event model available?

Comment: The game is being created under unity (C#). What do you mean by custom event model? If you mean Event System, yes, I have an in-house one. Just to clarify, my question is mainly  about creating and managing the wave creation inteligence while the player advances through the game.

Comment: As in you can create a class for a wave, and then add your own events to it. That way, the wave can "own" the entities which it spawns. Each entity then raises a custom `Died` event. The Wave handles the died event and checks to see if ALL of the entities have died, and if so, triggers the next wave. You can also have a simple timer running which triggers it after 10 seconds, or whatever other situations you might want.

Comment: As for generating the waves themselves, assuming you have different "levels" of enemies, I'd just give them a point value, and increase the amount of points available, then use some degree of weighting to divide out the different levels until the points are gone - really something like that would depend on what the waves consist of.

Comment: This is more or less the idea I had. But create something meanful, fun and challenging is pretty difficult because its procedural nature. On the other hand the added powerups, etc... make things pretty difficult I think.

Comment: I completely agree! The very first to do is to give things a value - both the enemies a difficulty value and the power-ups a helpfulness or negative difficulty value. There are lots of ways of picking a random set of stuff, some easy, some hard, and it's generally hard to make a fun random drop/spawn system - but the very first thing to do is understand what they're all worth relative to each other.

Comment: Agreed. Let's see what I can come with :). Thanks.